# what do [ *, %, >, D ] mean in ibuffer buffer?

Tags: ibuffer

When I open ibuffer to manage opened buffers I see   [ *, %, >, D ] markings.
There is no documentation describing what they mean. 
[image]

I wonder what do they mean (Emacs 26.1) ?

Comment: @Drew Please write the last sentence of [your comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/47836/what-do-and-mean-in-ibuffer-buffer#comment73668_47836) as an answer.

Comment: Tip: if you can't find documentation on something in a major mode using the normal methods, try `M-x customize-group RET <mode>`. Doing this for `ibuffer` shows you what the markers are called (and lets you change them).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`*` means the buffer has been modified, and `%` means it is read-only.

(Comments here corrected my initial misstatement that `*` means the buffer is marked for subsequent action. The character used for that is `>`, not `*.)

Comments here also mention, as a reminder, that the same characters `*` and `%` are used in the mode-line to indicate that a buffer has been modified and is read-only, respectively.)

---

(`h` (or as always, `C-h m`) in Ibuffer shows help on the major mode. But I see that it does not provide any legend for understanding such markings.  Please consider filing a bug/enhancement report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.)

Comment: When I open Emacs 26 and type `M-x ibuffer` and press the letter `m`, I see a mark in the form of a `>` symbol.  I see a variable named `ibuffer-modified-char` and its default value is `*`; and, I see a variable named `ibuffer-marked-char` and its default value is `>`.  The read-only portion is correct, which corresponds to the variable `ibuffer-read-only-char` with a default value of `%`.  And, although not asked by the O.P., there is a variable `ibuffer-deletion-char` whose default value is `D`.

Comment: Having `*` mean modified matches my experience as well.

Comment: Note also that `*` and `%` are used with these same meanings in the mode line for any buffer, such that you will see `--`, `**`, `%%`, or `%*` for unmodified, modified, read-only, or modified *and* read-only respectively.

Comment: @phils how can a buffer be modified and read-only?

Comment: A_P: it could be modified and THEN turned to read-only.

Comment: @lawlist: Thx; corrected.

Comment: @phils: Thx; added mention of the mode-line indications.